# Match all "errors:" but not "errors: 0"

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, match

I'm new to python and not looking for the "fast way" but for a hint.

I want to check a file for the pattern "error: " and print it with the line number so that I later on know where to look. If however the value is 0 (means "error: 0") this should not trigger.

Here's my "match all error:" script:

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import sys

lookup = 'errors: '
lookup2 = 'errors: 0'

with open(sys.argv[1]) as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if lookup in line:
            print('Line:', num, line)
```

I tried the "not" statament but this doesn't work:

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import sys

lookup = 'errors: '
lookup2 = 'errors: 0'

with open(sys.argv[1]) as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if lookup in line not lookup2:
            print('Line:', num, line)
```

Any hints?
Sorry for my probably very basic question...

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I understood. You want to print content if string **errors:** is there but if **errors: 0** is there then do not print.

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if lookup in line and lookup2 not in line:
            print('Line:', num, line)
```